# How make promise execute synchronously?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I use dom-to-image.js for converting dom to png image. As dom-to-image.js uses promise, the code executes asynchronously. I want to execute .then function synchronously.

I have the following code:

```
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById("main")).then(function(dataUrl) {
    console.log(dataUrl);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
});

console.log("this console should be executed after console.log(dataUrl)")
```

I want to execute .then function first, before executing `console.log("this console should be executed after console.log(dataUrl)")`.

Please tell me some way to achieve this.

Comment: why not put it within the then? or do chaining?

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/313880). Trust me, you _do not_ want to execute promises synchronously, because 1. this is impossible and 2. it would impede performance. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve here?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts there are valid use cases. If you have a legacy, sync code base integrating with an async one you may want to make sync stuff async and async stuff sync to prototype.

Comment: You can't stop the event loop. If you do, everything freezes, like an infinite loop. Asking to stop a Promise while it's not resolved is as bad request as asking to prevent `setTimeout` from waiting the time we requested for it to wait.

Answer (score 13):

There *are* of course legit reasons to force synchronous execution of a promise in js. The most obvious is when `require`'ing a file that needs to initialize using some asynchronous stuff, and optimization is not an overriding concern.

Seems like the package [synchronized-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/synchronized-promise) seems like it ought to do the trick. In your case (warning - untested..):

```js
const dti = () => docstoimage.toPng(document.getElementById("main"))
  .then(dataUrl => console.log('url: ', dataUrl))
  .catch(err => console.error('oops: ', err))

const sp = require('synchronized-promise')
const syncDti = sp(dti)
syncDti() // performs the 'synchronized version'

console.log("this console should be executed afterwards")
```

Comment: synchronized-promise relies on another package [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync) which modifies the Node.js event loop implementation in order to synchronously execute all code until the promise resolution is enqueued and handled. This will not work in a browser.

Comment: Excellent! Works with https://github.com/danday74/envsub library.

Comment: This spins the event loop from within your synchronous function.  That seems like an extraordinarily bad idea, since it could allow random other event loop tasks to run in the middle of your function.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention if it's done in browser or in NodeJs. For NodeJs that's possible by using `execSync` or `spawnSync` from `child_process`:

```js
import { spawnSync } from "child_process";

function doSyncStuff(domObj){
 const output = spawnSync(...);
 console.log("this logs in server");
 
 return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Async functions are a promise.
You have to use the promise syntax with them or use `await` (async-await syntax) on them in another async function.
An example of the regular promise syntax would be: `myPromise.then(() => {})`
For what you are looking for, you can use the promise syntax on them to wait for them as if they aren't a promise. Do take care though, as the code in `myPromise.then(() => {})` is synchronous and can't use async-await features. I've wrapped things in a main function but you don't need to for extra code but you don't need to.
You can then run the main function through the promise method.
For e.g:

```
async function myFunction() {
     // Do stuff
}

async function main() {
    // Do stuff
    await myFunction()
}

async function mySecondaryFunction() {
    // Do stuff
}

function mySynchronousFunction() {
    console.log("hello")
}

main().then(() => {
    mySynchronousFunction()
    mySecondaryFunction().then(() => {
        console.log("idk")
    }
})
```

See, we can use both types of functions!
Do know, though that this doesn't actually make promises synchronous.
It just acts like they're synchronous.

**EDIT**: Uhhh, I just realized you could put the `console.log` you want to execute after in both the `try` and `catch` functions.

Answer (score 0):

bit of a necro, but I'm the author of https://www.npmjs.com/package/synchronous-promise - which was around before this question was raised and does what you want (:

Answer (score -8):

For those stumbling upon this now:

If you're not concerned with IE support, you could use [async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to execute the promise as though it were synchronous. The `await` syntax will pause execution of the function until the promise resolves, letting you write the code as if there wasn't a promise. To catch an error, you wrap it in a `try/catch` block.

The only catch is that using the `await` syntax requires you to wrap it inside a function declared with `async`.

```js
async function toPng() {
  try {
    let dataUrl = await domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById("main"));
    console.log(dataUrl);
  }
  catch (error ) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
  }

  console.log("this console should be executed after console.log(dataUrl)")
}
```

Comment: Async await won't pause the function execution, that indeed return a promise. It's only syntactic sugar to svii using then\catch

Comment: this is just syntactic sugar that doesn't really change the nature of the execution

Comment: Another point here, top level await is now here in javascript! No need to wrap it into a function.