# Promise function runs after document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, dom, promise

I have a promise function that holds a promise function:

```
function readOrderFromDB(collection, tableID) {
            ....
            ....
        // inner promise function
        student.where('ID', '==', doc.data().studentID).get().then((studentDoc) => {
           studentDoc.forEach((d) => {
              document.getElementById(text).innerHTML += `<td style="text-align: center">
              ${`${d.data().firstname}  ${d.data().lastname}`}</td>`;
           });
        });
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += `<td style="text-align: center">${doc.data().numPayments}</td>`;
```

I have this problem, that when i run my code, the `document.getElementById(id)...` start before the inner promise function, althought the inner promise comes before it. i know that there should be a use of some sync function or wait but i didn't figure out how to put it correctly.

Comment: Turn `function` into `async function` if you are making asynchronous requests and use the `await` command to wait for a certain command to finish executing before the next line is executed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Please add `console.log(studentDoc)` inside `then` & share the result

Comment: results:   >Gl {fE: Zl, $E: qo, ME: Xs, EE: undefined, LE: null, …}
>Gl {fE: Zl, $E: qo, ME: Xs, EE: undefined, LE: null, …}

Comment: use promise chaining ... https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How make promise execute synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273583/how-make-promise-execute-synchronously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the last document.getElementById(id)... inside the then scope. Promises run on parallel, so if some part of your code relies on something you update inside the then scope, that part must be also on the then scope.

it should work:

```
function readOrderFromDB(collection, tableID) {
        ....
        ....
    // inner promise function
    student.where('ID', '==', doc.data().studentID).get().then((studentDoc) => {
        studentDoc.forEach((d) => {
            document.getElementById(text).innerHTML += `<td style="text-align: center">
            ${`${d.data().firstname}  ${d.data().lastname}`}</td>`;
        });
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += `<td style="text-align: center">${doc.data().numPayments}</td>`;        
   });
```