# how to make a syncrounous function like writefilesync not using callbacks, nor promises

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, callstack

first of all let me say i'm **not** asking anything about async/await or promises, i know these concepets, a also know that i can use top-level `await`s
but
i want to make "a single function" to block javascript on it's main thread (i know it's single-thread, anyway)

just to make it more clear you can assume `fs.writeFileSync` in node js, so if you have:

```
app.js:

1 console.log('first')
2 fs.WriteFileSync(file, data)
3 console.log('last')
```

javascript will stop at line number "2", it will complete the async job, and then it will log "last"

now, let's assume i have an asyn job like `setTimeOut(() => { console.log('job done'); }, 500)`, what i want is to make a function like `setTimeoutSync()` which can work for me exactly like `fs.writeFileSync`, so if i have:

```
index.js:

1 console.log('first')
2 setTimeoutSync()
3 console.log('last')
```

node index.js should provide an output like below for me:

```
first
job done
last
```

could anyone help me to provide the body of `setTimeoutSync()` function? (please consider that **i don't want to see any async or await keywords in my `index.js`**)

**and I DON'T WANT TO USE ANY THIRD-PARTY LIBRARY**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How make promise execute synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273583/how-make-promise-execute-synchronously)

Comment: "*javascript will stop at line, it will complete the async job, and then it will […]*" - nope. There is **no async** job here. The whole point of `writeFileSync` is that it's a **synchronous call**. It's not any different from the `console.log()` call in line 1.

Comment: @SergeySosunov not at all, i don't want to use any third-party library

Comment: The synchronous file system APIs are implemented in C (or C++ or whatever), and behave the way that platform file system operations have worked basically forever: they present a synchronous interface for those programming environments.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a synchronous `sleep(500)` function, or are you asking how to do this in general (and expect a `setTimeoutSync` implementation that calls `setTimeout`)?

Comment: So the basic answer is that you cannot do what you're asking.

Comment: "*i don't want to see any async or await keywords in my index.js*" - why not? It seems you already know the proper solution, so you should use it. Why are you so hell-bent on doing it synchronously?

Comment: @Pointy , could you explain me why?, and so how some libs like "synchronized-promise" can do this?

Comment: @Bergi , because my mind is hell-bented on how they do a thing like this when they wrote fs.writeFileSync

Comment: @TechDogLoverORkiaNasirzadeh The very first comment to the answer with synchronized-promise workaround - "Synchronized-promise relies on another package `deasync` which `modifies the Node.js event loop implementation` in order to synchronously execute all code until the promise resolution is enqueued and handled. This will not work in a browser." If you open the npm page of `deasync` you will see this: " The core of deasync is written in C++." And you can alsways check github to see actual implementation if curious.

Comment: @Pointy i have already saw writeFIleSync code behind and i know it was written in c++, so you guys are telling me that i can't do this in vanilla js??

Comment: @SergeySosunov i have already saw writeFIleSync code behind and i know it was written in c++, so you guys are telling me that i can't do this in vanilla js??

Comment: @TechDogLoverORkiaNasirzadeh If you just want to understand how `writeFileSync` is implemented, then you should ask for that, not [how to write a sleep function in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951021/1048572). But as Pointy explained, it's a function provided by the nodejs runtime that calls the OS APIs for writing files, and simply doesn't return until its done. There is no equivalent for sleeping offered in nodejs. You could of course write your own nodejs extension that does that, but it would still lead to bad js code :-)

Answer (score -2):

1- if you're programming modular: (your whole code is in methods, objects and classes)
use async functions

```
let pr = new Promise (res => {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log('job done'); res() }, 500);
})

async function asyncJob () { // do jobs in order
    return await pr;
}
function syncJob_1 () { // do sync job
    console.log('first');
}
function syncJob_2 () { // do sync job
    console.log('last');
}
function startApp () {
    syncJob_1();
    asyncJob().then(syncJob_2);
}
startApp();
```

2- if your programming is non-modular:
use top-level await's

```
let pr = new Promise (res => {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log('job done'); res() }, 500);
})
console.log('first');
await pr;
console.log('last');
```

### but:

so, considering others comments, i'm gonna answer my own question
the javascript runtime we are using in nodejs world, is written in c++, if we want to make a function like `setTimeoutSync()` we need to modify the Node.js event loop implementation, to do so, we should do it in c++

this job is already done by "deasync" package and "Synchronized-promise" package is relied on deasync to help you to do so in javascript

i beleive you can also make a very simple library for yourself to accomplish something like this:

```
synci.js:


class Jobs {
    jobs = [];
    jobIndex = 0;
    jobsCount = 0;
    constructor () {
    }
    doSync (func) {
        this.jobs.push(func)
    }
    done () {
        this.jobsCount = this.jobs.length;
        this.doJob(0);
    }
    jobDid () {
        this.jobIndex += 1;
        if (this.jobsCount > this.jobIndex) this.doJob(this.jobIndex);
    }
    async doJob (index) {
        let job = this.jobs[index];
        job();
    } 
}
export default Jobs;
```

and then you can have:

```
index.js:


import Jobs from './synci.js';

function setTimeoutSync (func) {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log('job done'); func() }, 500); 
}

const jobs = new Jobs();
jobs.doSync(() => { console.log('first'); jobs.jobDid(); });
jobs.doSync(() => { setTimeoutSync(()=>{ jobs.jobDid(); }) });
jobs.doSync(() => { console.log('last'); jobs.jobDid(); });
jobs.done();
```

above code will produce following output:

```
first
job done // afer 0.5 Sec
last
```